# why does this script fail to create a bucket in s3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have written a python script to connect to an amazon s3 server but it seems to fail when attempting to create a bucket (a time out error). I have omitted the secret key and id key for obvious reasons. Can anyone see what is wrong with this script? Thanks in advance

```
import boto
import sys, os
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.exception import S3ResponseError

LOCAL_PATH = '/Users/****/test'
aws_access_key_id = '****'
aws_secret_access_key = '****'
bucket_name = aws_access_key_id.lower() + '****'

class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass

conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
try:
    print "bucket name " + bucket_name;
    bucket = conn.get_bucket( bucket_name)
except TimeoutException:
    sys.exit("Connection timed out; this usually means you're offline.")
except S3ResponseError, exception_data:
    sys.exit(exception_data.error_message)
```

this is the error message i get:

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 941, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 937, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 759, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1140, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.timeout: timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you are trying to create a bucket but the `get_bucket()` method does not create a bucket, it returns an existing bucket.  If you want to create a new bucket, use `create_bucket()` instead.  The normal approach would be to first use `get_bucket()` to see if a bucket exists and if it does not, then call `create_bucket()`.

Also, I don't understand what this code is intended to do:

```
try:
    print "bucket name " + bucket_name;
    bucket = conn.get_bucket( bucket_name)
except TimeoutException:
    sys.exit("Connection timed out; this usually means you're offline.")
except S3ResponseError, exception_data:
    sys.exit(exception_data.error_message)
```

The `TimeoutException` class is a class you have created locally and the call to `get_bucket()` will never raise that exception because it doesn't know anything about it.  The call to `get_bucket()` should either return an existing bucket or raise an S3ResponseError in normal operation.

The fact that you are getting a timeout error from the `socket` module seems to suggest that there is something wrong with your networking setup.  Are you behind a proxy server?  Can you perform any operation against the S3 service (e.g. list keys in a bucket, etc.)?

Comment: i have tried this after creating a connection: bucket = conn.create_bucket(bucket_name); but i get the following error message The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to. I have so far been unable to perform operations.

Comment: ok i have figured out the above, i was not specifying a location but now i am getting an access denied message: Message>Access Denied